# Enzyme & Jest TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'touched' of '(0 , _formik.useFormikContext)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, formik

Am trying to unit test with Enzyme and Jest Formik , but am getting this erorr :

```
 TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'touched' of '(0 , _formik.useFormikContext)(...)' as it is undefined
```

Below is my unit tests :

```
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
describe('CountrySelector', () => {
    let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;

    beforeAll(() => {
        wrapper = shallow(<CountrySelector touched='' name={''} type={'internationalPrefix'} />);
    });

    it('should have a formik Field component', () => {
        wrapper.find(<><Field /></>)
    });
});
```

Now my react component is as below :

```
const CountrySelector = ({
  name,
  type,
  textFieldProps = undefined,
  withContext = true,
  countriesListProp = [],
  validateAttached = false,
  ...props
}: Props) => {
  const {
    touched,
    errors,
    setFieldValue,
    setFieldTouched,
    validateForm,
  } = useFormikContext<FormikValues>();
  const { countryList } = useCustomerCreatorState();
  const [countriesList, setCountriesList] = useState<CountryType[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (withContext) setCountriesList(countryList);
    else setCountriesList(countriesListProp);
    countriesList.sort((a: CountryType, b: CountryType) => a.country.localeCompare(b.country));
  }, [withContext, countryList, countriesListProp, countriesList]);

  const handleGetOptionLabel = useCallback(
    (option: CountryType) => (option ? getOptionLabel[type](option) : ''),
    [type],
  );

  const handleGetOptionSelected = useCallback(
    (option: CountryType, value: CountryType) =>
      option && value ? option.code === value.code : null,
    [],
  );

  const handleGetOptionRender = useCallback(
    (option: CountryType) => getOptionRender[type](option),
    [type],
  );

  const handleOnBlurCountry = useCallback(() => {
    setFieldTouched(name);
  }, [setFieldTouched, name]);

  const handleOnOpenCountryList = useCallback(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const optionEl = document.querySelector(`[data-name="${getOptionScroller[type]}"]`);
      optionEl?.scrollIntoView();
    }, 1);
  }, [type]);

  const handleOnChangeCountry = useCallback(
    (_: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, value: CountryType) => {
      setFieldTouched(name);
      setFieldValue(`${name}`, value);
      if (validateAttached) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          validateForm();
        }, 0);
      }
    },
    [setFieldValue, setFieldTouched, name, validateAttached, validateForm],
  );

  const handleRenderInput = useCallback(
    (params: AutocompleteRenderInputParams) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        {...textFieldProps}
        error={_get(touched, name) && !!_get(errors, name)}
        helperText={_get(touched, name) && _get(errors, name)}
        variant="outlined"
      />
    ),
    [errors, touched, name, textFieldProps],
  );

  return (
    <>
      {/* Todo: Field is used (instead of FastField) since the data is loaded asynchronously when the context does not exist. In a future we can use a different context for the creation of a customer profile. */}
      <Field
        name={name}
        onOpen={handleOnOpenCountryList}
        component={Autocomplete}
        options={countriesList}
        getOptionLabel={handleGetOptionLabel}
        getOptionSelected={handleGetOptionSelected}
        disableClearable
        renderOption={handleGetOptionRender}
        renderInput={handleRenderInput}
        onChange={handleOnChangeCountry}
        onBlur={handleOnBlurCountry}
        size="small"
        blurOnSelect
        clearOnBlur
        {...props}
        MenuProps={configMenuProps}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default memo(CountrySelector);
```

What could be adjusted ?